# How to use SolidColorBrush in ColorAnimation for Background property?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm a little confused by follow issue.

I have defined `SolidColorBrush` in XAML

```xml
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BuildItemMouseOverBackground" Color="#617492"/>
```

My style is:

```xml
<Style x:Key="BuildItem" TargetType="{x:Type Border}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundBorder}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BuildItemBackground}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" To="{StaticResource BuildItemMouseOverBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But this code throws exception:

```
ArgumentException: '#FF617492' is not a valid value for property 'To'.
```

If I set `To` as `Red` or `#123456`, the code works fine. So my conclusion is `To` expects color, not brush. But it's really odd, because I looked at `Border` class and found `Background` is brush actually.

[image: Border Class]

I tried to change `ColorAnimation` by this way:

```xml
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" To="{Binding Source={StaticResource BuildItemMouseOverBackground}, Path=Color}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
```

but looks like there is some multi-threading issue and I get exception

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot freeze this Storyboard timeline tree for use across threads.
```

So my question: what is the right way to use `SolidColorBrush` in `ColorAnimation`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BuildItemBackground}" />
```

In the above code, BackGround property can receive the SolidColorBrush type.
Therefore if BuildItemBackground type is SolidColorBrush as below then work well.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BuildItemBackground" Color="#3e3e42" />
```

But the code of the below can't receive the SolidColorBrush type.

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" To="{StaticResource BuildItemMouseOverBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
```

Therefore If you declared to the 'SolidColorBrush' type as the below. The compiler would show an error.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BuildItemMouseOverBackground" Color="#3e3e42" />
```

In the code like Animation, you have to use 'Color' type. therefore If you change the definition of the BuildItemMouseOverBackground to the Color as the below then it works well.

```
<Color x:Key="BuildItemMouseOverBackground">#3e3e42</Color>
```

Likewise, if you use BackGround or BorderBrush property to support animation as below then you have to use 'Color' type instead of 'SolidColorBrush' type.

```
<Border.BorderBrush>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderMediumColor}" Offset="0.0" />
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource BorderDarkColor}" Offset="1.0" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.BorderBrush>
```

In The above code, BorderMediumColor and BorderDarkColor have to be 'Color' type.
If the 'SolidColorBrush' type, the compiler would show an error.

If you use BackGroud or BorderBrush property as below.(case now) The type of color have to be 'SolidColorBrush'

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BuildItemBackground}" />
```

***Therefore, to solve this problem, first, change BuildItemMouseOverBackground type to the Color as below.***

```
<Color x:Key="BuildItemMouseOverBackground">#3e3e42</Color>
```

***Second, change the ColorAnimation code as below.***

```
<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="{StaticResource BuildItemMouseOverBackground}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
```

And It would work well.

I hope this information helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Because `To` property is a `Color` object and `BuildItemMouseOverBackground` is `SolidColorBrush`.

You should create a converter for convert `SolidColorBrush` to `Color` type.

```
public class SolidColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Color))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Color");

        return ((SolidColorBrush) value)?.Color ?? new Color();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use like this:

```
<converters:SolidColorConverter x:Key="ToColor"/>

<ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" To="{Binding Source={StaticResource BuildItemMouseOverBackground,Converter={StaticResource ToColor}}, Path=Color}" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
```